# How to build the dictionary from two other dictionaries by some condition on their values

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am new to functional programming and so can not imagen how to build the new dictionary based on two other dictionaries with similar set of keys. The new dictionary will have the entries with all keys but values will be selected/computed based on some condition.

For example, having two dictionaries:

```
D1: [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
D2: [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]
```

and condition to get the average of two values, the resulting dictionary will be

```
DR: [(1,60);(2,40);(3,75);(4,10)]
```

I need implementation in F#.

Please could you give me some advise.

Answer (score 3):

View them as two (or more...) lists of tuples that we concat makes it easier. The below solves your specfic problem. To generalise the  process aggeragting a list of values to something specific you would need to change averageBy to fold and provide a fold function instead of float. Assuming d1 and d2 mataches your exmaple.

```
   Seq.concat [ d1 ; d2 ] 
   |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|) 
   |> Seq.groupBy fst 
   |> Seq.map (fun (k, c) -> k, Seq.averageBy (snd >> float) c |> int) 
   |> dict
```

Comment: I like this. Mapping by `|KeyValue|` to unwrap the key-value pairs is clever!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use an external library, you could do this using [Deedle series](https://fslab.org/Deedle/series.html), which has various operations for working with (time) series of data.

Here, you have two data series that have different keys. Deedle lets you zip series based on keys and handle the cases where one of the values is missing using the `opt` type:

```
#r "nuget:Deedle"
open Deedle

let s1 = series [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)] 
let s2 = series [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]

Series.zip s1 s2
|> Series.mapValues (fun (v1, v2) ->
    ( (OptionalValue.defaultArg 0 v1) + 
      (OptionalValue.defaultArg 0 v2) ) / 2)
```

This may not make sense if this is a thing that you need just in one or two places, but if you're working with key-value series of data more generally, it may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

From a functional perspective I would use a `Map` data-structure, instead of a dictionary. You can convert a dictionary to a `Map` like this

```
let d1 = dict [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
let m1 = Map [for KeyValue (key,value) in d1 -> key, value]
```

But i wouldn't use a Dictionary and convert it, I would use a `Map` diretly.

```
let m1 = Map [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
let m2 = Map [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]
```

Next, you need a way to get all keys from both Maps. You can get the keys of a map with `Map.keys` but you need all the keys from both. You could get them by using a Set.

```
let keys = Set (Map.keys m1) + Set (Map.keys m2)
```

By adding two `Sets` you get a `Set.union` of both sets. Once you have them, you can traverse the keys, and try to get both values from both keys. If you use `Map.find` then you get an `optional`. You can Pattern match on both cases at once.

```
let result = Map [
    for key in keys do
        match Map.tryFind key m1, Map.tryFind key m2 with
        | Some x, Some y -> key, (x + y) / 2
        | Some x, None   -> key, x
        | None  , Some y -> key, y
        | None  , None   -> failwith "Cannot happen"
]
```

This creates a new `Map` data-structure and saves it into `result`. If both cases are `Some` then you compute the average, otherwise you just keep the value. As you iterate the keys of both `Map`s the `None,None` case cannot happen. A Key always must be in either one or the other.

After all of this, `result` will be:

```
Map [(1, 60); (2, 40); (3, 75); (4, 10)]
```

Again, here is the whole code at once:

```
let m1 = Map [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
let m2 = Map [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]

let keys = Set (Map.keys m1) + Set (Map.keys m2)
let result = Map [
    for key in keys do
        match Map.tryFind key m1, Map.tryFind key m2 with
        | Some x, Some y -> key, (x + y) / 2
        | Some x, None   -> key, x
        | None  , Some y -> key, y
        | None  , None   -> failwith "Cannot happen"
]
```

You also can inline the `keys` variable, if you want.

---

### Solution 2

When you have a `Map` then you can make use of the fact that adding a value always to a map, always creates a new `Map` data-structure. This way you are able to use `Map.fold` that traverses a `Map` data-structure and uses one of the map as the starting state while you traverse the other `Map`.

With `Map.change` you then can read and change a value in one step. If a key is already available you calculate the average, otherwise just add the value.

```
let m1 = Map [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
let m2 = Map [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]

let result =
    (m1,m2) ||> Map.fold (fun state key y ->
        state |> Map.change key (function
            | Some x -> Some ((x + y) / 2)
            | None   -> Some y
        )
    )
```

---

### Bonus: Adding Functions to Modules

It's sad sometimes that F# has so few functions on `Map`. But you need the a lot, you always can add a `union` function youself to the Module. For example:

```
module Map =
    let union f map1 map2 =
        let keys = Set (Map.keys map1) + Set (Map.keys map2)
        Map [
            for key in keys do
                match Map.tryFind key map1, Map.tryFind key map2 with
                | Some x, Some y -> key, (f x y)
                | Some x, None   -> key, x
                | None  , Some y -> key, y
                | None  , None   -> failwith "Cannot happen"
        ]

let m1 = Map [(1,100);(2,50);(3,150)]
let m2 = Map [(1,20);(2,30);(3,0);(4,10)]
```

This way you get a `Map.union` and you can specify a lambda-function that is executed if both keys are present in both maps, otherwise the value is used unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a couple of useful suggestions:

- [Group by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771706) with standard library functions from the `Seq` module, by [user1981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309055/user1981)
- [Use a specialized library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771893) for dealing with data series, by [Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek)
- [Use a map instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774185) (a functional data structure based on comparison), by [David Raab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338059/david-raab)

To this I'd like to add

- An imperative way, filling a combined dictionary by iterating through the keys of the source data structures, and finally
- A query expression

#### An imperative way

The average calculation is hard-coded with the type `int`. You can still have generic keys, as their type does not figure in the function, except for the `equality` constraint required for dictionary keys. You could make the function generic for values too, by marking it `inline`, but that won't be a pretty sight as it will introduce a host of other constraints onto the type of values.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let unionAverage (d1 : IDictionary<_,_>) (d2 : IDictionary<_,_>) =
    let d = Dictionary<_,_>()
    for k in Seq.append d1.Keys d2.Keys |> Seq.distinct do
        match d1.TryGetValue k, d2.TryGetValue k with
        | (true, v1), (true, v2) -> d.Add(k, (v1 + v2) / 2)
        | (true, v), _ | _, (true, v) -> d.Add(k, v)
        | _ -> failwith "Key not found"
    d

let d1 = dict[1, 100; 2, 50; 3, 150]
let d2 = dict[1, 20; 2, 30; 3, 0; 4, 10]
unionAverage d1 d2
```

#### A query expression

It operates on the same principle as the answer from user1981, but for re-usability the average function has been factored out. It expects an arbitrary number of `#seq<KeyValuePair<_,_>>` elements, which is just another way to represent dictionaries that are accessed through their enumerators.

As the query expression uses `System.Linq.IGrouping` under the hood, this is upcast to a regular sequence to reduce confusion. Then there's the conversion to float for `Seq.average` to operate on, because the type `int` does not have the required member `DivideByInt`.

```
module Dict =
    let unionByMany f src = 
        query{
            for KeyValue(k, v) in Seq.concat src do
            groupValBy v k into group
            select (group.Key, f (group :> seq<_>)) }
        |> dict
    
Dict.unionByMany (Seq.averageBy float >> int)  [d1; d2]
Dict.unionByMany Seq.sum [d1; d2]
Dict.unionByMany Seq.min [d1; d2]
```